# Should I include both @id and @type for node referencing in JSON-LD structured data?

Tags: json, google-schemas, structured-data

While creating node referencing to avoid doing the same thing again and again, do I need to only specify the @id or both @id and @type?

For example, for a brand description, if the JSON-LD used on the **homepage** is:

```
"brand": {
      "@type": "Brand",
      "@id": "https://example.com/#brand",
      "name": "Brand Name",
      "description": "Brand description"
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "sameAs": ["link1", "link2", "link3"]
    }
```

then which of the following is the right way to reference the brand on the **product pages**?

Option 1:

```
"brand": {
      "@type": "Brand",
      "@id": "https://example.com/#brand"
    }
```

Option 2:

```
"brand": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/#brand"
    }
```

Option 3:

```
"brand": "https://example.com/#brand"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to specify the @id, the other parameters then get merged into the one entity.

I typically add a few extra parameters if I'm referencing an entity on a different page. e.g. @type, name, url. This helps consumers know a little about the referenced entity without crawling the alternate page. And it can stop testing tools from complaining.

In your example I'd do at least option 1 and maybe also add url.